Reinforcement Learning DDPG: creating a meaningful heat map of action value and state
Algorithm: Double Deep Policy Gradient
Output of Actor-Network: Mean action value and variance
Observation (states): x,y coords
My goal is to create a heat map that has a meaningful representation of how the mean action values, depending on the observation (state) are developing during the training of my agent.
Currently, I take a measurement (= action values & state) of one step every X steps.
My environment is similar to FrozenLake and the agent might need quite some steps to reach other areas of the environment (leading to few measurements at locations other than the starting area).
Is there a smart way to create meaningful heatmaps here that are "straightforward" to interpret? I'm happy to receive ideas and feedback as to how I could improve my approach (e.g. how often should I measure? Should I measure a batch of steps each interval? Should I plot the states against the variance too? etc.).
